# Prove limit of sequence

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove that sequence $y_n = \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k x_k}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k} \to L$ if sequence $x_n \to L$.

I think I shoud use that $\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k}{n} \to L$, but how?

UPD: I solved it using Stolz–Cesaro theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Stolz-Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) (of which this exercise is an excellent illustration) you get

$$\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \frac {\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k x_k} {\sum \limits_{k=1}^n k} = \lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \frac {\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k x_k - \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n-1} k x_k} {\sum \limits_{k=1}^n k - \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n-1} k} = \lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \frac {n x_n} n = \lim \limits _{n \to \infty} x_n = L .$$

Comment: Thank you, I remembered it simultaneously!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $x_k\to L$, then you can control the size of $\vert x_k - L \vert$ for large $k$. Try to use this to bound the sum in the numerator, both from above and below.