# Show that $\lim_n a_n = 0$ implies $\lim_n \frac{\sum_{m=1}^n m a_m}{\sum_{m=1}^n m} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let ${a_n}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. I want to show that
$$
\lim_n a_n = 0 \implies \lim_n \frac{\sum_{m=1}^n m a_m}{\sum_{m=1}^n m} = 0.
$$

My attempt is like this:

> Fix any $\varepsilon>0$. There exists $N$ such that $|a_n|<\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$. Then,
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> \left|\frac{x^{1}+2x^{2}+\cdots+mx^{m}}{1+2+\cdots+m}\right| & =\left|\frac{x^{1}+\cdots+Mx^{M}+\cdots+mx^{m}}{1+\cdots+M\cdots+m}\right|\\
>  & <\left|\frac{x^{1}+\cdots+Mx^{M}+\varepsilon((M+1)+\cdots+m)}{1+\cdots+M\cdots+m}\right|\\
>  & \le\left|\frac{x^{1}+\cdots+Mx^{M}}{1+\cdots+M\cdots+m}\right|+\varepsilon\left|\frac{(M+1)+\cdots+m}{1+\cdots+M\cdots+m}\right|\\
>  & <\left|\frac{x^{1}+\cdots+Mx^{M}}{1+\cdots+M\cdots+m}\right|+\varepsilon
> \end{align*}.
> $$

However I get the feeling that this is going nowhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove limit of sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602367/prove-limit-of-sequence) – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_n%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Csum_%7Bm%3D1%7D%5En%20m%20a_m%7D%7B%5Csum_%7Bm%3D1%7D%5En%20m%7D%24&p=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine by now. Fix any $\varepsilon > 0$. Then, there exists $N$ such that $|a_m| \le \varepsilon$ for $m \ge N$.

Now you have:
$$ |\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n ka_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n k}| = |\frac{\sum_{k=1}^N ka_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n k} + \frac{\sum_{k=N+1}^n ka_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n k}| \le \frac{\sum_{k=1}^N |ka_k|}{\sum_{k=1}^n k} + \varepsilon $$

Now, choose $M$ so that for $n \ge M$ you have $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^N |ka_k|}{\sum_{k=1}^n k} \le \varepsilon$ (you can find such $M$, because the numerator is fixed, and $\sum_{k=1}^n k \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.)

Hence, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, you found $K = \max\{N,M\}$ such that for $n \ge K$, you have:
$$ | \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n ka_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n k} | \le 2\varepsilon $$